# HighChart: Add xaxis dynamically doesn't consider what type I give it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to add a xaxis dynamically using:

```
         $('#highchartcontainer').highcharts().addAxis({
                id: i,
                title: {
                    text: tag.name,
                    style: {
                        color: color
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: color}, true);
```

ref: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addAxis

But when it starts to draw I get this strange number as shown in the picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQya6.jpg

How do I get the newly added xaxis to be datetime?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I sloved it by moving `type` out from `xAxis`

```
    $('#highchartcontainer').highcharts().addAxis({
            id: i,
            title: {
                text: tag.name,
                style: {
                    color: color
                }
            },
            type: 'datetime',
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: color}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

For further clarification:

The way your code is set up is the equivalent of nesting an `xAxis` object inside of another `xAxis` object, and applying the `type` property to the child object.

All of the properties that you are sending in that options object are automatically wrapped in the `xAxis` object that gets created - nesting another one is unnecessary, and ineffective.

So, your options as sent are like doing this in your main config:

```
xAxis: {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },
  id: i,
  title: {
    text: tag.name,
    style: {
      color: color
    }
  },
  ineWidth: 1,
  lineColor: color
}
```

Which wouldn't work.